# Java String to Float

Tags: java, string, floating-point, arraylist

I am attempting to turn an array list of strings into an arraylist of floats. I have declared the two as such:

```
ArrayList<Float> AFFloat = new ArrayList<Float>();
ArrayList<String> AFUni0 = new ArrayList<String>();
```

AFUni is an array list that was parsed from a file. It holds values such as:

> [0.059, 0.059, 0.029, 0.412, 0.029, 0.452, 0.386, 0.432, 0.114,0.318, 0.159,0.045, 0.432, 0.477, 0.045...]

I am trying to make those string values into actual numeric values with this set of code:

```
for (String wntFl:AFUni0){
  AFFloat.add(Float.valueOf(wntFl));
}
```

But for some reason it isn't working. It is coming back with this error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0.114,0.318"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1222)
    at java.lang.Float.valueOf(Float.java:388)
    at allelefreq.AlleleFreq.main(AlleleFreq.java:122)
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? 
Thanks

Comment: That `String` value contains *two* float values, you didn't do the splitting correctly, it seems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like some values are separated by ", " while others, like your example, only by ",". This could be the reason for the failed recognition.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in your Exception

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0.114,0.318"
```

You pass the `"0.114,0.318"` as `wntFl`, that is why you have NUmberFormatException

You should assure that your input is valid.

First you should split the input, then you can parse it.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message shows you, the value it's failing on is `"0.114,0.318"` (i.e., NOT `"0.114"` or `"0.318"`, but multiple numbers in one `String`), which is not a valid number. However you're populating your `ArrayList`, you're getting multiple values in a single `String`. You can fix this by fixing the code that populates the array or using `String.split(",")` to get an array of the values and loop over that before casting to floats.

Answer (score 0):

`0.114,0.318` is not a valid float (Observe ,`in between), that is why`NumberFormatException`

You may need to first `split()` the string which returns array and then pass values to `Float.valueOf(str[i]`)

Comment: Ah yes, that would explain it. I am not sure how I overlooked that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Separators are not quite constant in all string-stream. Try to find problem in this way.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `String.split(",")` because `0.114,0.318` is not a valid float

Answer (score 0):

You don't do the splitting correctly.
This kind of project works very well (but its just example)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList<Float> floats = new ArrayList<Float>();
        ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();

        strings.add("0.123");
        strings.add("1.123");
        strings.add("0.423");
        strings.add("34.423");
        strings.add("0.000");

        for(String str : strings) {
            floats.add(Float.valueOf(str));
        }

        for(Float fl : floats) {
            System.out.println(fl);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be the reason of `Internationalization`/`Localization`, In many languages `.` is replaced with `,/،`

Just like in Spanish   http://translate.google.com/#auto/es/10.1

Or in Arabic http://translate.google.com/#auto/ar/10.1.

You have to take care of localization in case of string to float conversion.